# Android : Using context to get all TextView

Tags: android

Is it possible to get all the TextView in an activity and change their values without knowing any ID? May be something like UI automtor tool that return UI hierarchy but at Java programming level. I tried to Google this but couldn't find any solution.

**Edit**

What I am trying to achieve here is, I have an external library/SDK which modifies all textView values.  So I am planning to initialise it on top of each activity and let the SDK do the work of modifying all the TextViews value.

Comment: @MikeM.  Once I have a List of TextView, I will fetch the ids associated with them, if given to TextView

Comment: No, because all textviews have different ids and to differentiate them is difficult and confusing.

Comment: You can do that by initialising parent control and looping through it

Answer (score 12):

You can use this code to find all `TextView`s in your layout, just pass the parent view and it will do the rest:

```
public static void findViews(View v) {
    try {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                // recursively call this method 
                findViews(child);
            }
        } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
            //do whatever you want ...
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the parent View from context? What I am trying to achieve here is, I have an external library/SDK which modifies all textView values.  So I am planning to initialise it on top of each activity and let the SDK do the work .

Comment: @AbhishekBatra : you mean you havent access to your parent layout; so how did you use setContentView() ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

First initialize the parent control and use this

```
    ArrayList<TextView> list = new ArrayList<TextView>();

    for( int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++ ){

    if( layout.getChildAt( i ) instanceof TextView )
    {
    // change the values of text view here
((TextView)layout.getChildAt( i )).setText("your text here");

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have activity layout then try as follows

```
ArrayList<EditText> myEditTextList = new ArrayList<EditText>();

for( int i = 0; i < activityLayout.getChildCount(); i++ ){

if( activityLayout.getChildAt( i ) instanceof EditText )
myEditTextList.add( (EditText) activityLayout.getChildAt( i ) );

}
```

and getting their values

```
for(int i=0;i < myEditTextList.size();i++){
   System.out.println(myEditTextList.get(i).getText().toString());
 }
```

Hope this will helps you.